# Are there iPhone hacker community groups that meet in the real world?

Tags: iphone

Just to clarify, by hacker community group I mean people who just like to get together once a month or once a week to have a beer (or tea or juice) and share with others what they've been working on and maybe even help each other out.

I know this already exists in the general hacking world, but I'm wondering if an iPhone specific one is running.

It would be also good to know if there is one in London, England (where I live). If not, I might consider starting one up! Any interest?

Feel free to comment on any of the above, especially if you are interested in forming one.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be exactly what you are looking for

London iOS developer group

http://www.linkedin.com/groups?gid=1798655
http://iphonedevelopergroup.blogspot.com/

It will also be worth checking out NSCoderNights and CocoaHeads